# Source Imagettftext

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

I need the source of this function (imagettftext) in php. I can't find the source (it is implemented by php).

Somebody knows where can I find it?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in C, but I just browsed the source of PHP 5.3.3 and it looks like it's in `ext/gd/gd.c` starting at line 3879.

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds on google got me this:-
https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/overview

It is implemented in C though, not PHP and is part of the GD library.